# Modal bootstrap is not showed until function ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm novice in web programming yet but I' m trying to learn :)

I want to hide a modal to show another modal("Please wait screen"),to wait for a function call to end (loadData()). But the first modal gets hidden and then the screen fades until function ends and only then the "Please Wait" modals appears.

Any help is welcome.

Ps: Sorry for my bad english...

**HTML**

First modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" id= "btn1"  class="btn btn-primary"  data-target="#modal1">Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second modal

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="myPleaseWait" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">
                    </span> Processing data...
                 </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info
                    progress-bar-striped active"
                    style="width: 100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#btn1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#modal1').modal('hide');
    $("#myPleaseWait").modal("show");
    loadData();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's modal class exposes a few events for hooking into modal functionality.

**show.bs.modal**
This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.

**shown.bs.modal**
This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

**hide.bs.modal**
This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.

**hidden.bs.modal** 
This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

**loaded.bs.modal** 
This event is fired when the modal has loaded content using the remote option.

```
$('#btn1').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $('#modal1').modal('hide');
   $('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $("#myPleaseWait").modal("show");
   });
   loadData();
});
```

For more details refer [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: may be you should loadData() Inside the function

    $('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $("#myPleaseWait").modal("show");
     loadData();
   });

Create a js fiddle with the code.It will be much easier to chk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sri, with your explanation I could resolve it.

```
$('#btn1').click(function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

    $('#modal1').modal('hide');
    $("#myPleaseWait").modal("show");
    $('#myPleaseWait').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        loadData();
    });
});
```